# jQuery : if statement, parent name and children

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child, parent, children

I have an `if` statement in which every child are displayed. But I want to display their parent too.There are multiple parents which have children. So the goal should be to display the parents as `<ul>` with multiple `<li>` of their children.

```
for (var i in objects) {
        obj = objects[i].name;
        objID = objects[i].id;
        if (obj == "") {
            daeParent = objects[i].parent.name;
            parentDaeParent = objects[i].parent.parent.name;
            $("#objectH").append("<ul>" + parentDaeParent + "</ul>");
            $("#objectH").append("<li class='object-hierarchy-name dae-hierarchy "+objID+" ' attr-id="+objID+">" + daeParent + "</li>");
        }
}
```

I'm able to display each time the parent + the children, but not the parent once.

I don't know if my problem is clear.

**[EDIT]**

`objects` is an array in which I have different collada objects imported with three.js.

After processing, I would have this HTML:

```
<h3>Parent1</h3>
<ul> 
    <li>Children1</li>
    <li>Children1</li>
</ul>
<h3>Parent2</h3>
<ul> 
    <li>Children1</li>
    <li>Children2</li>
</ul>
[...]
```

Comment: Are you able to post the structure inside `objects` and what the HTML markup is you expect to see after your code is done processing?

Comment: Neither in pure JS nor in jQuery does the `object.parent` do anything - in jQuery it would be `parent()` and in vanilla JS it would be `parentNode` - Just a rough guess as there is not enough information here.

Comment: `<ul> <h3>Parent1</h3>
    <li>Children1</li>` is invalid HTML. The direct children of `ul` can only be `li`

Comment: What you're attempting to achieve is invalid markup.  The only valid child of a `ul` is an `li`.  Having an `h3` in there is technically incorrect to begin with.

Comment: Unrelated to whether the HTML is valid or not, you will _first_ have to sort your items into an object or a nested array with the children being contained in the parent before printing the list as an ul - You are now printing a UL for every child, disregarding who the parent is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

> but not the parent once

You could keep a record of which parents have been added then only add if not in the record (an array), or (slower) check the html if the parent exists

You can use `.filter` to find an item based on its text, eg:

```
var parent = $('#objectH>ul').filter(function(){ 
    return $(this).text() === parentDaeParent;
});

if (!parent.length) {
     $("#objectH").append("<ul>" + parentDaeParent + "</ul>");

parent.append("<li ...")
```

Comment: Thank you, you understood what i want :)
I just made a mistake, because `objID` is an id of each chidren. So I can't use it for the parent.

Comment: Does your object hierarchy include an ID for the parent?  `objects[i].parent.parent.id` and/or `objects[i].parent.id`

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)
I'm using the parent.parent.name